# Is there an application or a site grouping addresses by user graphically?

Tags: privacy, websites

Addresses can be grouped as belonging to the same user (or, better, same "account") by grouping together the addresses that participate as inputs to a single transaction, and doing it transitively. This has been done in the [recent paper by Shamir and Ron](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/584.pdf), by [some previous researchers](http://anonymity-in-bitcoin.blogspot.com/2011/07/bitcoin-is-not-anonymous.html) and can be done by [znort's parser](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=88584.0). I know this is not 100 % accurate but I'm fine with it.

What I'm looking for is a site that displays the results of such grouping graphically, possibly with transactions between accounts as well.

I've read about such a site on bitcointalk.org, but I can't find the topic any more. I'm looking for the url of the (now possibly defunct) site or the bitcointalk topic describing it.

Comment: Wouldn't that be dependent on being able to associate a transaction with a geographic location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bitcointalk topic:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=103609.0

Comment: If anyone knows what happened to blockviewer.com (the site's offline now), or if there are any similar applications/sites, I'm still interested.

Comment: It is still being developed.  The latest is found here: http://toolongdidntread.com

Answer (score 1):

The tool is called Blockviewer.  The website, blockviewer.com, no longer exists.  However, the source code is available on Github: https://github.com/thallium205/BitcoinVisualizer.  Thus, you might be able to download the source code, compile it, and run it on your own machine.

You can also read [the original blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225133954/http://toolongdidntread.com/bitcoin/the-bitcoin-social-network-part-1/) introducing some of the ideas behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned site, blockviewer.com, is now down.

There should be some type of search/querying engine that allows you to find the addresses associated with a given address based on the classic user-generating algorithm.

Anecdotally, my university might be hosting such an engine by the end of the summer. We're also looking at Javascript-based visualization engines to host the data through.

Sadly, however, it seems that no such visualizer (or even public data source) currently exists, as far as I can tell.